# What does the dispose() function actually do under the hood in flutter

Tags: flutter, dispose

When we use some controllers in our widgets, I see it that we just make instances, fine
But when we call as an example:

```
controller.dispose()
```

what actually the flutter engine exactly do for that constructor

Comment: It's all open source. Just ctrl + click it to go to the implementation. Usually it is to get rid of listeners or other references. To prevent memory leaks

Comment: I did, I followed where it's going, but I just have an idea, so I asked here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official source [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/dispose.html), the `dispose` method is a general API that is used commonly by all `ChangeNotifier` classes such as `TextEditingController`, `FocusNode`, etc

> Discards any resources used by the object. After this is called, the
> object is not in a usable state and should be discarded (calls to
> addListener will throw after the object is disposed).
>
> This method should only be called by the object's owner.

In short, it's "required" to prevent unwanted possibility of memory leaks (memory leaks cause that boost in RAM usage of the app).

The implementation code itself cleared up all Listeners attached to it, and it also works as a trigger to help cleanup unused resources, turning off continuous working entities such as `Timer`s, releasing Animation related resources, when the parent object is not used anymore.

> There are many use cases of what happened beneath, just look up into the open source codebase of Flutter itself. For example, try to lookup `TextEditingController`'s implementation of `dispose` method

Yes, this is quite an abstract concept to explain, but releasing unused resources will improve your app's performance, although not directly visible.